# Which network protocol use for sharing a storage to 5-10 mac client?

Tags: storage, share

i can choose one between a Mac Server and a Synology Nas to share a disk for 5-10 mac clients (not windows) . 
When i've to share storage, Which protocol is best suited for Mac World ? Afp, NFS, iScsi ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's all Mac, AFP... SMB/CIFS is fine as well.